# azure service fabric stateful service - how to mirror sql schema?

Tags: sql, architecture, microservices, azure-service-fabric

This question is related to architecting a stateful fabric service.

We have a bunch of tables in sql like "Patients", "Patient_visits", "Doctors", "Patient_Clinical_Data", "Patient_Doctors" etc.

My questions..

1. Should we create reliable collections that exactly mirror this
   table schema in order to replicate the whole DB in the middle tier?
2. How do we do complex joins across these reliable dictionaries
   especially when the data is spread over multiple partitions?
3. Let's say I have 1 billion patients visit records. I decided to
   create 10 partitions of 100 million each based on some hash
   function. I would think the query to search across 100 million
   records would itself take a long time in a single partition. [not
   talking about multiple simultaneous queries when system is under
   load]. How do we tackle this? Can we load balance a stateful service
   under a single partition [since in my case I will have 100 million
   records in a single partition and want to distribute the query load
   to multiple servers]. Is it even practical to have these many
   records in a single partition?

Regards

Comment: Please consider reformatting with paragraphs so the question is more readable.

Comment: Thank you. made it readable..

Comment: There is no simple answer, it depends on particular tables, kind of data they store, functions on that data. For sure you should not blindly recreate the same schema on reliable collections. You should decide what data should be located in one service due to close relation and what data could be separated. Try to google information on the next subjects: data denormalization in microservices, data sharing in microservices, data duplication in microservices to get more deep and clearer view on the problem.

Comment: Thx @cassandrad. you pointed me in the right direction. Now, the only question is should I go with "Eventual consistency" by duplicating the data or have a master service for each "entity" and expose API's from each service to do data sharing.<p>My other question is, if I had large amount of data in a single partition on service fabric, can I introduce a load balancer for speeding up queries? If we don't, we will run into the same bottlenecks when we had a single DB. The only difference is we now have a single microsservice node servicing all requests.</p>

Comment: @teeboy I think it will be better to create two separate new questions to receive good answers. It doesn't really matter what do you use for storing data — Service Fabric or any other sharded storage like MS SQL or MySql. In general, for your first questions, answers are already exist on SO, but you ask so general thing that nobody will tell you how to do it in details, only general suggestions. For the second question, if you have large amount of data in a single partition, then you need to split that data to several partitions. Partitions already are for speeding up.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the solution to this being more on the database side rather than on the application consumer side. Performance with table sizes this big is not my specialty, but what about beefing that database server up with a significant amount of memory in order to keep a lot more in faster to access storage?